# Javascript: function error() disappears

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am new in programming and i was wondering why my program doesn't work. I try to submit a form. If a question has not been answered, the program must do first alert("Sommige vragen moeten ingevuld worden!");. Then the program must display an error beneath the question. When i submit the form with one question left open(the one that is required), then it says 'Sommige vragen moeten ingevuld worden'. That's good. But the error doesn't work. It appears on the screen and then it vanished. I want that error to stay on the screen so that the respondent can correct his value. After correcting, I want the form to be 'true' so that it will be send.

This is the javascript-file:

```
var genderMale = document.getElementById('genderMale');
var genderFemale = document.getElementById('genderFemale');
var work1 = document.getElementById('work1');
var work2 = document.getElementById('work2');
var work3 = document.getElementById('work3');
var work4 = document.getElementById('work4');
var work5 = document.getElementById('work5');
var use1 = document.getElementById('use1');
var use2 = document.getElementById('use2');
var use3 = document.getElementById('use3');
var use4 = document.getElementById('use4');
var use5 = document.getElementById('use5');
var ysm = document.getElementById('ysm');
var nsm = document.getElementById('nsm');
var digital1 = document.getElementById('digital1');
var digital2 = document.getElementById('digital2');
var digital3 = document.getElementById('digital3');
var ingevuld = true;



function required(){
if( (!genderMale.checked) && (!genderFemale.checked) ){             
    ingevuld = false;
}

var x = document.getElementById('age').value;                           
if (x<21 || x>100 || x==""){                                            
    ingevuld = false;
}

if( (!work1.checked) && (!work2.checked) && (!work3.checked) && (!work4.checked) && (!work5.checked) ){ 
    ingevuld = false;                                               
}

if( (!use1.checked) && (!use2.checked) && (!use3.checked) && (!use4.checked) && (!use5.checked) ){      
    ingevuld= false;    
}

if( (!ysm.checked) && (!nsm.checked) ){         
    ingevuld = false;
}

if( (!digital1.checked) && (!digital2.checked) && (!digital3.checked) ){        
    ingevuld = false;
}

if(!ingevuld){                                                                      
    alert("Sommige vragen moeten ingevuld worden!");
} else{
    window.open("confirm.html");
    window.close("Gebruikersonderzoek_medici.html");
}

}

var error1=document.getElementById("question1");
var error2=document.getElementById("question2");
function error(){
error1.innerHTML="";
    try{ 
        if(!genderMale.checked && !genderFemale.checked)    throw "vink een van de opties aan";
    }
    catch(err){
    error1.innerHTML="Deze vraag is vereist: " + err + ".";
    }


var x = document.getElementById('age').value;
error2.innerHTML="";
    try{ 
        if(x=="")       throw "vul een cijfer in";
        if(isNaN(x))    throw "vul een cijfer in";
        if(x>67)        throw "te hoog cijfer";
        if(x<21)        throw "te laag cijfer"; 
    }
    catch(err){
    error2.innerHTML="Deze vraag is vereist: " + err + ".";
    }

}


function validator(){
required();
error();
}
```

And this is the HTML-file:

```
<title>Gebruikersonderzoek medici</title>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="meesterproef.css">
</head>


<body>

<h1>Elektronische medicijnkaart</h1>

    <form name="meertenenquete" id="submit1" onsubmit="validator();" target="_self">
        <p class="margin">*1. Wat is uw geslacht?</p>                                                                                                                                     
            <input id="genderMale" type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Man<br>
            <input id="genderFemale" type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Vrouw<br><br>
                <div class="error" id="question1"></div>

        <p>*2. Wat is uw leeftijd (in cijfers)?</p>                                                                                                                 
            <input id="age" type="number" min=21 max=67> jaar<br>
                <div class="error" id="question2"></div>

        <p>3. Welke van de volgende opties beschrijft het best uw beroep?</p>                                                                                       
            <select id="job">
                <option value="kiesuit">Kies uit...</option>
                <option value="huisarts">Huisarts</option>
                <option value="bedrijfsarts">Bedrijfsarts</option>
                <option value="anesthesioloog">Anesthesioloog</option>
                <option value="anesthesiemedewerker">Anesthesiemedewerker</option>
                <option value="apotheker">Apotheker</option>
                <option value="apothekersassistent">Apothekersassistent</option>
                <option value="chirurg">Chirurg</option>
                <option value="verpleegkundige">Verpleegkundige</option>
                <option value="dermatoloog">Dermatoloog</option>
                <option value="cardioloog">Cardioloog</option>
                <option value="gynaecoloog">Gynaecoloog</option>
                <option value="longarts">Longarts</option>
                <option value="geriater">Geriater</option>
                <option value="internist">Internist</option>
                <option value="kinderarts">Kinderarts</option>
                <option value="orthopeed">Orthopeed</option>
            </select><br><br>
            Iets anders namelijk: <input type="text" name="alternative" size="75"><br>

        <p>*4. Hoe lang oefent u uw beroep uit in de gezondheidszorg?</p>                                                                                           
        <input id="work1" type="radio" name="work" value="5year">Minder dan 5 jaar<br>  
        <input id="work2" type="radio" name="work" value="15year">Tussen de 5 en 15   jaar<br>
        <input id="work3" type="radio" name="work" value="30year">Tussen de 15 en 30 jaar<br>
        <input id="work4" type="radio" name="work" value="40year">Tussen de 30 en 40 jaar<br>
        <input id="work5" type="radio" name="work" value="moreyear">Meer dan 40 jaar<br>

            <p>*5. Hoe vaak gebruikt u een medicijnkaart in uw functie?</p>                                                                                             
        <input id="use1" type="radio" name="use" value="countyear">Een aantal keer per jaar<br>
        <input id="use2" type="radio" name="use" value="countmaand">Een aantal keer per maand<br>
        <input id="use3" type="radio" name="use" value="countweek">Een aantal keer per week<br>
        <input id="use4" type="radio" name="use" value="countday">Een aantal keer per dag<br>
    <input id="use5" type="radio" name="use" value="countno">Ik maak geen gebruik van dat<br>

        <p>6. Wat zijn de voor- en nadelen van de huidige papieren medicijnkaart?</p>                                                                               
            Voordelen: <br><textarea name="advantage" rows="3" cols="100"></textarea><br>
            Nadelen:   <br><textarea name="disadvantage" rows="3" cols="100"></textarea><br>

        <p>*7. Gebruikt u een smartphone en/of tablet op het werk</p>                                                                                               
            <input id="ysm" type="radio" name="smtb" value="yes">Ja<br>
            <input id="nsm" type="radio" name="smtb" value="no">Nee (vraag 8 overslaan)<br>

                    <p>8. Op welke van de onderstaande besturingssystemen?  (meerdere opties mogelijk)</p>                                      
            <input type="checkbox" name="opsystem" value="android">Android<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="opsystem" value="windowsphone">Windows Phone<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="opsystem" value="ios">IOS (Apple)<br><br>
            Anders, namelijk: <input type="text" name="alternative" size="75"><br>

        <p>9. Zou het prettig zijn wanneer een medicijnkaart toegankelijk is via de werkplek?</p>       
            <input type="radio" name="access" value="yes">Ja<br>
            <input type="radio" name="access" value="no">Nee<br>

    <p>*10. Als er een digitale versie komt van een medicijnkaart, gaat u hem dan gebruiken? </p>                                                               
    <input id="digital1" type="radio" name="digital" value="absolutelynot">Absoluut niet<br>
    <input id="digital2" type="radio" name="digital" value="dontknow">Ik weet het niet<br>
    <input id="digital3" type="radio" name="digital" value="probably">Zeer waarschijnlijk wel<br><br>
    Indien niet, waarom niet?<br>
    <textarea name="whynot" rows="3" cols="100"></textarea><br>

        <br><input type="submit" value="Verzenden"/>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="meesterproef.js">
    </script> 

        <p class="asterisk">* Deze vragen zijn vereist!</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors do not stay because the page is submittion, you are not cancelling the form submission if it fails

```
onsubmit="validator();"
```

needs to be

```
onsubmit="return validator();"
```

and `validator` needs to return true/false

Comment: I just figured it out. I had onsubmit = validator();return false;